# Chrome extension manifest v3 Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to load (inject) in page a javascript code. The javascript file is local to the extension. the filepath is 'js/somefile.js'.

```
const basePath = chrome.runtime.getURL('');
    fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL(filePath), { mode: 'same-origin' }) // <-- important
      .then((_res) => _res.blob())
      .then((_blob) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener('loadend', (data) => {
          callback(data.currentTarget.result, basePath);
        });
        reader.readAsText(_blob);
      });

const scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.innerHTML = scriptText;
    scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    const scriptElement = document[injectLocation].appendChild(scriptTag);
    if (removeImmediately) document[injectLocation].removeChild(scriptElement);
```

My web accessible resources are:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [{
    "resources": [
    "js/*.js",
    ],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
  }],

"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' 'https://apis.google.com/' 'https://www.gstatic.com/' 'https://*.firebaseio.com' 'https://www.googleapis.com' 'https://ajax.googleapis.com'; object-src 'self'"
  },
```

The error that I get is:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Wq/CW2mxkri68TjkuaA0+LnU0capVpyiEuSA5NOVNfU='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Comment: The code you've shown is unrelated to the error which says you have an inline script which is a common problem in the popup or options pages: [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721457).

Comment: You are right, Indeed I am trying to inject said script in page. I saw that executeScript is a viable alternative. How can I aim to inject the code of a script in the current tab?

Comment: Use a [content script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532567).

Comment: I updated the code with the offending line. It is the appendchild part that is blocked because V3 does not allow for injection of scripts. I am using a content script to do this but it still fails.

Comment: Currently you use a content script to inject another script in [page context](/a/9517879), which is a very special thing needed to extract/access JS variables/functions from the page. To inject the code you don't need that. Simply inject the js file as a content script (declaratively or via executeScript).

Comment: I see makes a lot more sense now, thank you

Comment: It's sucks, how to deal with third-party, in case they (third party) have some updates? End up compiling a new own script and include it into the extension bundle?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can resolve the inline execution error by changing `scriptTag.innerHTML = scriptText;` to `scriptTag.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(filePath);`, no need to fetch the script. Manifest v3 seems to only allow injecting static scripts into the page context.

If you want to run dynamically sourced scripts I think this can be achieved by having the static (already trusted) script fetch a remote script then eval it.

UPDATE: example extension, with manifest v3, that injects a script that operates in the page context.

```
# myscript.js
window.variableInMainContext = "hi"
```

```
# manifest.json
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "example extension",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["inject.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "myscript.js" ],
      "matches": [ "https://*/*" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
# inject.js

const nullthrows = (v) => {
    if (v == null) throw new Error("it's a null");
    return v;
}

function injectCode(src) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    // This is why it works!
    script.src = src;
    script.onload = function() {
        console.log("script injected");
        this.remove();
    };

    // This script runs before the <head> element is created,
    // so we add the script to <html> instead.
    nullthrows(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
}


injectCode(chrome.runtime.getURL('/myscript.js'));
```

Comment: I've tried this when v3 was released and I could not access any of the javascript variables from the top window (website context). By access I mean. Say there is a window.text variable. Can I inject a script that does window.text='something';. So I cannot read the variable but I can still change it. From what I understand, this is not possible under v3.

Comment: It's definitely possible to inject a script that does `window.text='something'`. I'm updating my answer with an example.

Comment: Yes it does work. I was able to verify it as well. What an elegant and simple solution! thank you so much!

Comment: Can this work with an external script like paypal's smart button?

Comment: I'm getting this error on the remove call when I try to use it in typescipt: "TS2339: Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'GlobalEventHandlers'."

Comment: That saved me so much time, thanks <3

Comment: This works! However, it looks like it is bypassing the content security policy (CSP), so I'm wondering if at some point this could break.

Comment: "Manifest v3 seems to only allow injecting static scripts into the page context."

I work on extensions at Google. This is definitely true.

Comment: To get it to work for me in v3 I had to add the `myscript.js` to `content_scripts` as well.

Comment: I'm shocked this actually worked.  Been fighting with this problem all week, since upgrading to V3.  This method didn't work in V2, but I'm glad it does now!!  Thank you!!!!

Comment: @JosephAstrahan Did you get an answer to your question? How did you make it work?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning unfortunately I didn't get it to work, I just forced the users to go to my website instead

Answer (score -5):

Download the script files and put it on your project to make it local. It solved my content security policy problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).